# How to use LyX to create PDF file from the command line

Tags: xetex, lyx, pdf

I'm using LyX for technical documentation and want to automate the process of creating PDF files.

Within LyX, I can simply click the button "View PDF (XeTeX)", and LyX performs the whole build process for me: it creates a .tex file, does some bibliography magic, and uses XeTeX to create the final PDF file.

What I'm looking for is a way to call LyX from the command line and get the same result. So far, I've only managed to generate a plain .tex file (using `--export-to xetex`). However, when I run xelatex on the generated file, it keeps showing errors that don't occur when building using LyX. Is there a way to get LyX to do the work?

My system: Windows 7 64bit, LyX 2.1.0

Comment: I could have sworn this didn't work before, but now it works great. @HarishKumar: If you make this an answer, I'll accept it. For the record: The "short name" of "PDF (XeTex)" is "pdf4".

Comment: Daniel: I have added an answer. Thanks for the `pdf4` thing :)

Comment: You can go to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts` and create new key-bindings for `buffer-export xetex` and `buffer-export pdf4`. You can refer to `Help > Lyx Functions` for the command syntax including specifying a destination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command sequence for exporting `.lyx` files to pdf/dvi (etc) from command prompt is

```
lyx --export FORMAT myfile.lyx
```

where `FORMAT` is the short identifier of the format you want to export, e.g., "dvi" for DVI files or "pdf2" to export PDF via pdflatex. You may see the `File Formats` pane in LyX's preferences dialog for a list of the available formats.

For example, to convert `.lyx` file to pdf using `xelatex`, the command will be

```
lyx --export pdf4 myfile.lyx
```

On the other hand, you may prefer to use a `.bat` file so that you can put the `.bat` file in the same directory as your `.lyx` file and simply double click on it.

```
@ECHO ON
cls

REM export lyx files to pdf using xelatex

CD /D %~dp0
SET Programa="lyx.exe"
for %%A in (*.lyx) do %Programa%  --export pdf4 %%A
Pause
```

Save the above as `lyxbatch.bat` (say), in the same folder as your `.lyx` file. Double clicking on this file will export all `.lyx` files in the current folder to `pdf` files using `xelatex. You have to have`lyx.exe` added to your system path.

<sub>Untested as I don't have lyx installed in this computer. If there are any hassles please let me know.</sub>

Comment: Just to add that as noted on the [LyX Wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ImportExport), you may have to add `start /wait` to the front of the command, e.g. `start /wait lyx --export FORMAT myfile.lyx`.