# LyX command line not working as expected

Tags: lyx, command-line

I want to use LyX to generate a pdf from a .lyx file from command line and I found how to proceed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175345/how-to-use-lyx-to-create-pdf-file-from-the-command-line)

Problem is that when I try to do like that, no output is generated, and no error is returned, just a new prompt line appears. Also trying a simple command like `lyx --help` doesn't return anything. If I type just `lyx` the GUI LyX gets effectively launched [image]

I am on Windows 10, LyX version 2.3.4.4, which is otherwise working as expected.

Comment: I think this might be an issue specific to Windows. It would be nice to fix the root issue that's causing this behavior. Please open an issue on www.lyx.org/trac.

Comment: @scottkosty , I agree it being an issue specific for WIndows. I opened a bug report on lyx trac as suggested, let's see if it gets managed